# Trying to delete file by extension

Tags: python, python-3.x

So I am trying to delete files by extension and everything seem to be working fine - I can find the DRX files, count and display them but when I try to remove them it just doesn't seem to do anything. I'm sure I've done something really obvious wrong.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import os
import sys
import site
import threading
import time
from os import path 
from os import listdir
from os.path import isfile, join



print ("")
file = (input("Please drag and drop the folder containing DRX files you wish to delete : "))
path = file[:-1]
os.chdir(path)
drx = [x for x in os.listdir() if x.endswith(".drx")]
amount = (str(len(drx)))

print("")
print("")
print("")
print ('I have found ' + amount + ' files with the .drx extension and these will now be deleted')
print("")
print("")
print(*drx,sep='\n')
print("")
print("")
print("")
exts = ('.drx')

for item in path:
    if item.endswith(".drx"):
        os.remove(item)
```

Comment: Print out `item` in `for item in path`. Do you get a list of file names, or a list of letters? Just re-use the `drx` list that you already gathered.

Comment: A good idea when interacting with files is to check whether the file exists before you do anything with it.

Comment: Your script is mess. Why are you printing empty strings multiple times?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`drx` is your list of files that end with `drx`, you can do

```
for item in drx:
    os.remove(item)
```

`path` is only a string (the name of the path you want to search), so looping over it will loop over the letters.

Comment: Ahhh I see !! So even though above the path variable is defined as the input from the user it doesn't work like that. Thanks for clearing that up!!

Comment: Yes, path is defined to be the user input, so it will be some string containing e.g. `"/foo/bar/"`, but in order to get a list of files in the directory that is described by this string, you need to use `os.listdir` like you have done above

Answer (score 0):

```
for item in path:
    if item.endswith(".drx"):
        os.remove(item)
```

1. Here your path is something like `"/home/path/to/file.drx"` so looping over that will give your character one by one as pointed by @FlyingTeller.
2. you don't need `if item.endswith(".drx")` again. you have already done that with list comprehensiton `drx = [x for x in os.listdir() if x.endswith(".drx")]`. just use it.

`for item in drx:
    os.remove(item)`

3. Your code is messy. you can do `print("\n"*3)` for printing 3 blank lines